# Jackson Deserialization: unrecognized field

Tags: java, json, jackson

From the tutorial I had the impression that this should work (simplified example):

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public static class Qux {
        private String foobar;
        public String getFoobar() {
            return foobar;
        }
        public void setFoobar(String foobar) {
            this.foobar = foobar;
        }
    }
}
...

String in = "{ \"bar\": \"123\", \"qux\" : {\"foobar\": \"234\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo obj = mapper.readValue(in, Foo.class);
```

However, I get an error

```
UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "qux" (Class Foo), not marked as ignorable
```

I'm running 2.2.2

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? `ObjectMapper` by default will try to map all your fields.

Comment: The "Full Data Binding (POJO) Example" from  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: That example doesn't show any missing fields. There's special configuration you need to set to ignore those. See my answer.

Comment: I don't want to ignore those fields... I'd like to have them set on the inner Qux class

Comment: Your Foo class doesn't have a Qux class field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you pull your `Qux` class out of `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    // added this
    private Qux qux;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    // added getter and setter
    public Qux getQux() {
        return qux;
    }
    public void setQux(Qux qux) {
        this.qux = bar;
    }
}

public static class Qux {
    private String foobar;
    public String getFoobar() {
        return foobar;
    }
    public void setFoobar(String foobar) {
        this.foobar = foobar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you sir!

Comment: The location of the Qux class I doubt was the solution. Adding the qux property is the remedy.

Comment: @BrentWorden Leaving the Qux class where it was _could_ have worked, but would have also required the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` attribute.

Comment: @LukeWillis No extra annotation is needed.  Here is an example unit test that demonstrates the deserialization using a default object mapper and unannotated classes: https://gist.github.com/brentworden/6386024

Answer (score 3):

You can configure `ObjectMapper` to ignore fields it doesn't find in your class with

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

If not configured this way, it will throw exceptions while parsing if it finds a field it does not recognize on the class type you specified.

Answer (score 2):

The Foo class needs an instance property of type `Qux` for automatic deserialization to work.  The way the Foo class is currently defined, there is no destination property to inject the `qux` JSON object values.

```
public class Foo {
   private String bar;

   public String getBar() {
       return bar;
   }

   public void setBar(String bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   }

   // additional property 
   private Qux qux;

   public Qux getQux() {
       return qux;
   }

   public void setQux(Qux value) {
       qux = value;
   }

   public static class Qux {
       private String foobar;

       public String getFoobar() {
         return foobar;
       }

       public void setFoobar(String foobar) {
           this.foobar = foobar;
       }
    }
}
```